# Quantum walk for quantum simulated annealing in arXiv: 1512.03806

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-walks

I'm studying quantum walk and quantum simulated annealing. While reading the paper [Quantum algorithms for simulated annealing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03806), I feel a little confused about the quantum walk they gave in Sec 2.1 *Quantum walks for QSA*, which is

> $W=X^\dagger PXPRPX^\dagger PXR,$

where $P$ is the swapping opertor, $R=\mathbb{I}-2|\vec{0}\rangle\langle \vec{0}|$, and $X$ satisfies

$$X|\sigma_i\rangle |\vec{0}\rangle =\sum_{j=0}^{d-1} \sqrt{Pr_\beta (\sigma_j|\sigma_i)} |\sigma_i\rangle 
 |\sigma_j\rangle, \qquad
\vec{0}=\sigma_0,$$
and $\{\sigma_i\}_{i=0}^{d-1}$ can be considered as the full space of configurations.

As mentioned in the paper,

> the detailed balance condition implies $W\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} \sqrt{\pi_\beta(\sigma_i)} |\sigma_i\rangle|\vec{0}\rangle=\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} \sqrt{\pi_\beta(\sigma_i)} |\sigma_i\rangle|\vec{0}\rangle$

where $\pi_\beta(\sigma_i)$ in the eigenstate are the probabilities given by the Gibbs distribution dependent on $\beta$. And

> the goal of QSA is to prepare the corresponding eigenstate of $W$.

My questions are:

1. How do we write $X$ in the operator form? Is $$\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} \sum_{j=0}^{d-1} \sqrt{Pr_{\beta}(\sigma_j|\sigma_i)} |\sigma_i\rangle\langle \sigma_i| \otimes |\sigma_j\rangle\langle \vec{0}|$$ correct?
2. Which qubits do the $R$s act on? I think it's the first qubit for the first $R$ and the second one for the second, otherwise, the $R$s would make no sense...
3. What does this walk mean? With the assumptions about $X$ and $R$, I tried to compute $$W\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} \sqrt{\pi_\beta(\sigma_i)} |\sigma_i\rangle|\vec{0}\rangle,$$
   which seems to be
   $$\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}\sqrt{\pi_\beta(\sigma_i)} \sum_{b=0}^{d-1} \sum_{c=0}^{d-1} (-1)^{I(i=0)+I(b=0)} \sqrt{Pr_\beta(\sigma_b|\sigma_i) Pr_\beta(\sigma_i|\sigma_b) Pr_\beta(\sigma_c|\sigma_b) Pr_\beta(\sigma_b|\sigma_c)} |c\rangle|0\rangle$$ ($(-1)^{I(i=0)+I(b=0)}$ could take different forms due to the location of $R$s). But is there any relationship between the *balance condition* and the walk *c->b->i->b->c* ?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) that's one way to write it, yes. It is only defined by its action on inputs of the form $|\sigma_i\rangle|0\rangle$ so you can write it in operator form in multiple ways by having it act differently on states orthogonal to $|0\rangle$. 2) maybe $R$ acts as the identity in the first space, although this is not written explicitly?  3) what do you mean with "what does this walk mean"?

Comment: Thank you glS! Yeah perhaps it's a good idea to look into every possibilities of $R$s' locations. 3) I don't understand why this walk was used...I tried to read https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1571, but failed to link them together :( Just realized it could be the *bipartite quantum walk* in the old paper and $W$ here could be separated into two reflection operators through full projectors. I also forgot to read the references related to the bipartite quantum walk lol. I'll try to find out the correspondence between them :)